# How to use Python3.5 in Pycharm or Spyder for Windows 10

Tags: pycharm, spyder, python-3.5

I am using Anaconda on Windows. Pycharm and Spyder work well when I use python 3.8. However, I need python3.5 to install Orfeo Toolbox(remote sensing image processing software). When I tried to open Pycharm or Spyder under python3.5 I got a message that python 3.5 unsupported. Is there any way to work with Python 3.5?
I would really appreciate any advice.

Comment: I can reproduce errors installing Spyder in an Anaconda env with Python 3.5. Maybe you could find help on the Spyder bugtracker?